# Is there a way to autofill a form field based on a link?

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

I'm trying to have a button link generate a specific code into a form field when clicked, but can't seem to find any solution that works. I know there's got to be a Javacript answer, but none of the suggested solutions are getting it done.

Form code:

```
<div class="nm-checkout-form-coupon">
        <form class="checkout_coupon" method="post" style="display:none">
            <p class="form-row">
                <input type="text" id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Physician Code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" id="coupon_code" value="" required />
            </p>
            <p class="for-row">
                <p>Don't have a Physician Code? <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#physcode">Get one here!</a></p>
                <!-- Physician Code Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade access-code-popup" id="physcode" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="physcodelabel" >
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                   <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <p>AQ Skin Pro products are available exclusively through participating clinics and physicians offices. If you do not have an Exclusive Physician Code, click "generate a code" below.</p>
                      <button class="nm-simple-add-to-cart-button single_add_to_cart_button button alt" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onClick="fillFields('coupon_code')" alutocomplete="off">Generate a Code</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </p>
            <p class="form-row">
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php _e( 'Apply Physician Code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you better describe the flow that you're envisioning? `apply_coupon` has a value pasted in from php, where are you trying to access it and how is it failing?

Comment: Same as here: https://venusskin.com/customer/account/create/

Under Personal Information in the left column, the first item is Exclusive Access Code (Click here if you don't have an access code).  When you click the link, the modal pops up, generates the code into the filed and closes.

Comment: If you look at the source code at that link you'll find the relevant JavaScript at line 481 — or search for `code-prompt`.

Comment: Tried using their code, didn't work.  They're on Magento and I'm on WooCommerce here: http://designatwork.net/c3/checkout/#

Comment: You're still not providing enough information. What field do you want to populate with your coupon code? What's the element that you expect users to click on to make your `checkout_coupon` form display?

Comment: Currently, they can put in a Physician Code and apply it to their order just like a coupon.  But, the text below says "Don't have a Physician Code? Get one here!" When they click that, a modal pops up with a button that says "Generate a Code".  When they click that button, it should generate a code into the Physician Code field (the one with id="coupon_code").  The code generated can be the same every time since it's just a general use code.

Comment: Who is responsible for writing the `fillFields` function that isn't presently defined? Is that code that you wrote but didn't finish or did you get that from the WooCommerce documentation?

Comment: Sorry, onClick="fillFields('coupon_code')" was part of another attempted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current attempt isn't far off: `<button class="nm-simple-add-to-cart-button single_add_to_cart_button button alt" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="fillFields('coupon_code')" alutocomplete="off" id="gencode">Generate a Code</button>`

If you want to keep it simple **REPLACE** the onclick code to:
`document.getElementById('coupon_code').value = 'THECOUPONCODE';`

You should end up with something like: `<button class="nm-simple-add-to-cart-button single_add_to_cart_button button alt" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="document.getElementById('coupon_code').value = 'THECOUPONCODE';" alutocomplete="off" id="gencode">Generate a Code</button>`

Comment: OK, that got me closer, but I need it to only fill 'THECOUPONCODE' when they click on "Generate a Code" in the modal popup.  I implemented your code above and it just autofills the form field with 'THECOUPONCODE' on page load.

Comment: Where did you implement the change? I see the field prepopulated with 'gen2015' but if I inspect the 'Generate a Code' button I still see `fillFields('coupon_code')` if I go to http://designatwork.net/c3/checkout/

Comment: I've updated my answer in the hope of making it clearer. Please give it another look and see if you still run into problems.

Comment: Here: `<button class="nm-simple-add-to-cart-button single_add_to_cart_button button alt" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="document.getElementById('coupon_code').value = 'gen2015';" alutocomplete="off" id="gencode">Generate a Code</button>
                      <script>
                        document.getElementById('coupon_code').value = 'gen2015';
                      </script>`

Comment: It's working now! I've been grinding on this issue for days. Thank you so much Alfredo!